# Scheduled perfmon skips every other day

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, perfmon

I have a perfmon data collection set, scheduled to start every day.  I get data files only every other day.  I've checked the schedule details; all days are selected. 
I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The "Stop Condition" limit specified "duration 1 day" but did not specify "restart the data collector set at limits."  Without checking the restart option, the collector stops after one day, and only starts when a new midnight rolls around.

The "restart" checkbox needs to be checked.